# Call error only on some browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I've made this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
//query rest che trova tutti gli amici dell'utente corrente        
type: 'GET',
async: false,


url: "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now",

success: function(data) {

  time_now=data;

    },
    error: function(data) {

      console.log("ko" );
    }


});
```

in chrome works perfectly but in firefox and on mobile android goes in error callback.
In firefox the error is(written in red): 
GET 'http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json   200 OK

Comment: And what's the error ? Don't just log "ko" but the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This server](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now) must be old, it doesn't set any cross-origin authorization header.

But luckily, the home page explains it's JSONP compatible and gives an example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myCallback(json) {
    alert(new Date(json.dateString));
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

You can also adapt your code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=?",
    success: function(data) {
     time_now=data.dateString;
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("ko" );
    }
});
```

Note also that I removed the `async:false`. Not only is it incompatible with JSONP, it's also **always** a bad idea.

Comment: Yes but my ajax call is correct, I don't understan why works only on chrome

Comment: Do you use very old browsers ?

Comment: No. Browsers shouldn't let your call pass. Can't you just fix your code as shown ? (BTW **never** use `async:false`).